# Need help in pure c list implementation

Tags: c, list, structure, printf, scanf

I am trying to do linked list of persons in c.
All my methods work in `main()` until I put them into while loop (for reading commands from user). Everything compiles, but when I try to run it, it crashes returning random values.
Here are parts of my code.

Structure:

```
struct Person{
             const char* name;
             const char* sex;
             int age;
             struct Person* next;
} *head;
```

Method insert:

```
void insert(struct Person* h, char*n, char* s, int a){

    for(; h->next != NULL; h=h->next){}

    struct Person* p = (struct Person*) malloc(sizeof(struct Person)); 
    p->name=n;
    p->age=a;
    p->sex=s;
    p->next=NULL;
    h->next=p;
}
```

and main in which it doesn't work:

```
int main()
{
    struct Person Maciek={"Maciek", "Male", 20, NULL};
    head = &Maciek;
    int comand = 0;


    while(comand != 6){
        printf("Choose command:\n 1-insert person \n 2-delete by index \n 3-delete by name \n 4-display by index \n 5-print whole list \n 6-exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &comand);
        if(comand == 1){
            printf("Name, Gender, Age\n");
            char* name;
            char* sex;
            int age;            
            scanf("%s, %s, %d", &name, &sex, &age);
            printf("Name %s, Sex %s, Age %d", name, sex, age);

            insert(head, name, sex, age);
        }

        if(comand == 2){
            printf("2\n");
        }

        if(comand == 3){
            printf("3\n");
        }

        if(comand == 4){
            printf("4\n");
        }

        if(comand == 5){
            printf("5\n");
        }

    }

     return 0;
}
```

I am quite new to C/C++, and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try a debugger?  You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: Turn up your warning settings - you should be getting format mismatch warnings, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if(comand == 1){
        printf("Name, Gender, Age\n");
        char* name;
        char* sex;
        int age;            
        scanf("%s, %s, %d", &name, &sex, &age);
```

Here you are using dangling pointers (which are pointing anywhere in memory), you should use `malloc` to allocate some memory or use char arrays, and as Carl Norum pointed out you shouldn't have `&` in your `scanf` call as you need to provide some `char*` and not `char**`. You can do it like this (this code is vulnerable to buffer overflow, don't use that in production code, consider using `fgets`+`sscanf`):

```
char name[50];
char sex[20];
int age = 0;
scanf("%s, %s, %d", name, sex, &age);
```

In your insert function:

```
 struct Person* p = (struct Person*) malloc(sizeof(struct Person)); 
 p->name=n;
 p->age=a;
 p->sex=s;
```

You are replacing p->name with n, instead of copying the content of n into p->name. You want:

```
struct Person *p = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
p->name = malloc(strlen(n)+1);
if(p->name == NULL) {
  //error handling...
}
strcpy(p->name, n);
p->sex = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
if(p->sex == NULL) {
  //error handling...
}
strcpy(p->sex, s);
p->age = a;
```

Comment: `name` and `age` shouldn't have `&` in the `scanf` call, either.

Comment: char* name =(char*) malloc(20*sizeof(char));  
    char* sex =(char*) malloc(6*sizeof(char)); I 've corrected into this, it still doesn't work, could you help me again?

Comment: remove the & operator in your scanf call. And you don't need to cast the return of malloc in C, you would need that in C++ only. `char *name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));`

Comment: `char *name = malloc(20)` is fine.  `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: Your edit suggesting the use of arrays is probably not helpful to the OP, either.  His `insert` function doesn't copy the data, so it'll be continually overwritten.

Comment: I agree that the answer was incomplete, but not that it was not helpful ;-)

Comment: It would be sensible to use `strdup()`, or measure the length of the strings (remembering to add 1 for the `'\0'`) before allocating.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading strings into pointers that have not been initialized with allocated memory.